# How to match url with url regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have url regexp which will find the urls. Here is my regexp

```
(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?/gi
```

but, this regexp is not matching with following url

```
https://www.dpd.co.uk/apps/tracking/?parcel=15505969270050*18538&geoSession=37418a6f-ed43-405f-a596-782d7d78a9651
```

how I can match with these type of urls. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use: `[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.*~#?&//=]*)`

Or with HTTPS prefix: `https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~*#?&//=]*)`